# Преобразование Drawable

Tags: java, android, realm

Начал свое знакомство с `Realm` и столкнулся с проблемой что такие классы как `Calendar` и `Drawable` не поддерживаются `Realm`, оно и логично. `Calendar` я стал хранить в `byte` а вот с `Drawable` так не получается. Хотелось бы совета как хранить `Drawable` (векторный).

Comment: Вроде бы как Drawable икто не хранит в базах. Хранят просто ссылки на ресурсы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хранить в бд какую-либо графику очень плохой подход... Лучше хранить в ней некоторые идентификаторы изображения, а в приложении получая из базы идентификатор подгружать нужный ресурс.

Если все же именно в базе нужно хранить описание drawable и иначе совсем никак, то рекомендуют делать 2 базы - одну со всеми данными и идентифиаторами ресурсов, а вторую с одной таблицей - идентификатор-текст. В текстовом поле храним прям текст из xml, описывавшего drawable, получив текст заворачиваем его в `XmlPullParser` и используя `Drawable.createFromXml` получаем объект который можно скормить в src или background в рантайме

А как вы Calendar храните в byte это для меня прям большой вопрос... Или вы день недели сохраняете?